# glTexSubImage2D 1282 - invalid operation in gl es 3.1

Tags: binding, opengl-es, textures, compute-shader

I am trying to use:

```
layout (binding = 0, rgba8ui) readonly uniform uimage2D input;
```

in a compute shader. In order to to bind a texture to this I am using:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, texture_name, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA8);
```

and it seems that in order for this bind to work the texture has to be immutable so I've switched from:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

to:

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8UI, width, height);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

But this generates "Invalid operation" (specifically the glTexSubImage2D() call generates it). Looking in the documentation I discovered that this call may cause 1282 for the following reasons:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the texture array has not been defined by a previous glTexImage2D or glCopyTexImage2D operation whose internalformat matches the format of glTexSubImage2D.

GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if type is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 and format is not GL_RGB.

GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if type is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1 and format is not GL_RGBA
```

but none of these is my case.

The first of them might seem to be the problem (considering I am using glTexStorage2D(), not glTexImage2D() )but this is not the problem because in case of float texture the same mechanism works:

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, width, height);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

instead of:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

This is probably irrelevant but both methods work well on PC.

Any suggestions on why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try out my solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The *internalFormat* you use in `glTexImage2D` and `glBindImageTexture` should be the same and be compatible with your sampler. For a `uimage2D`, try using `GL_RGBA8UI` everywhere.

Also, for transfers to `GL_RGBA8UI` (and other integer formats) you need to use `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` as *format*.

```
glBindImageTexture(0, texture_name, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA8UI);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Using the *format* `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` should also make the `glTexSubImage2D` variant work.

Comment: I tried. It didn't cause any error, but didn't upload any data to my texture either. The solution I found was to use GL_RGBA8 for internal format and GL_RGBA for format. Thanks for your suggestion.